# $name is getting indexed

Tags: sxa, solr, sxa-search, index

We are on `Sitecore 10.1` and `Solr 8.4`. We are using Filter (Checklist) component and found out $name is showing on the page.

[image: site]

Upon checking the Solr, the $name is getting indexed as well.

[image: solr]

This is the Solr index configuration.

```
<fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
    <field fieldName="contenttype" returnType="stringCollection" />
</fieldNames>
```

I tried to delete all the index files and re-indexed everything several times but $name is still getting indexed.

How can I stop $name getting indexed?

Comment: If there is still "$name" on the page, it will be indexed again. First you need to make sure that all of your Content Types have valid titles so they are displayed correctly on the page.

Answer (score 1):

`$name` is a token that replaces by item name when we create item in the content tree. But sometimes accidentally or because of some issue during item creation,it doesn't change to the item name and remains as `$name` in the field. When you will do the indexing of the item you will find that `$name` is the index. To fix this issue you need to make sure -

- No item field has `$name` as content (you can find the item name/id
  from solr)
- Make sure the item publish properly and you can check the
  value in the web database
- Make sure you are using the `latest version` in your code to get the item, the older versions may have the $name value
- Make sure you don't have any computed field which is not working properly and add content a `$name`

Answer (score 1):

`$name` is just a token which will be replaced by item name, if you will create item first and then add `$name` in standard value later then in `$name` will be reflect into your item because of standard value but next time when you create item, it will take item name instead of `$name` so I would suggest to update `$name` manually (if there are few items) or using `Powershell` script, you can replace `$name` with `item name`.

Answer (score 0):

You might have been missed updating the $**name** value from the field. Please make sure that you are not using the $**name** in the item. If everything is good then please do the reindex again it will remove all the old values.